# Flutter inappwebview scroll not working inside the NestedScrollView TabBarView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-inappwebview

Im new to flutter, i have added the webview(inappwebview) inside the TabBarView, but when i try to scroll down the web page, it is not scrolling down, below i have added my code and screenshot

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: DefaultTabController(
          length: 5,
          child: Scaffold(
              body: NestedScrollView(
            headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
              return <Widget>[
                new SliverAppBar(
                  title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
                  pinned: true,
                  floating: true,
                  bottom: TabBar(
                    isScrollable: true,
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(child: Text('Flight')),
                      Tab(child: Text('Train')),
                      Tab(child: Text('Car')),
                      Tab(child: Text('Cycle')),
                      Tab(child: Text('Boat')),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ];
            },
            body: TabBarView(
              children: <Widget>[
                InAppWebView(initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse("https://flutter.dev/"))),
                Icon(Icons.directions_transit, size: 350),
                Icon(Icons.directions_car, size: 350),
                Icon(Icons.directions_bike, size: 350),
                Icon(Icons.directions_boat, size: 350),
              ],
            ),
          )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

screenshot:
[page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fGNm.jpg)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try adding a gesture detector, like this:

```
InAppWebView(
gestureRecognizers: Set()..add(Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(() => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer())),
initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse("https://flutter.dev/"))),
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, this is the place you have to look, gesture detectors.

Comment: thank you @Huthaifa Muayyad sir, now webview scroll is working, but it created 2 more new problems, [1]. App bar is not getting hidden when webview scroll is scroll down, [2]. i visit 2nd tab, scroll down causes appbar hidden, then came to webview tab (assume appbar is already hidden/scrolled), then part of the webview html is not visible and not able to scroll top to the hidden part, i have attached the image for the reference https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zbfil.jpg

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider opening a new post, with the details of the new problem, and mark this as resolved. So that every post had a specific problem and a specific solution, thanks!

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad thank you very much for this solution. I need to point out that use flutter_inappwebview: ^5.3.2 and I could scroll when I was running Flutter SDK 1.?? but it stopped scrolling in Flutter SDK 2.0.6